# Use ffmpeg muxer to MPEG2TS , audio stream can't play in vlc palayer

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I use libavformat to encapsulate an h264 stream and an aac stream into an mp4 file which is playable. However, when encapsulated into a ts file, it works fine in the Win10 player, but no audio in the vlc player. When encapsulating, the audio stream is printed, but with fprobe, the audio stream is printed with channel=0. What could be the reason for this?
And h264 source file is no pts.So I caculate it by myself.

[ffprobe print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W960w.png)

[ffmpeg print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz4qV.png)

Here is my code.

```
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>


static void log_packet(const AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx, const AVPacket* pkt, const char* tag)
{
    AVRational* time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;
    printf("%s num=%d  den=%d\n", tag, time_base->num, time_base->den);
    printf("%s: pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
        tag,
        av_ts2str(pkt->pts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
        av_ts2str(pkt->dts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
        av_ts2str(pkt->duration), av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
        pkt->stream_index);
}

int main()
{
    const char* in_filename_v = "test.h264";
    const char* in_filename_a = "aoutput.aac";
    const char* out_filename = "lol.ts";


    //Video Input AVFormatContext
    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_v = NULL;
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_v, in_filename_v, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_v %s", in_filename_v);
        return -1;
    }

    //Find Video Stream Info
    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_v, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_v stream info");
        return -1;
    }

    //Audio Input AVFormatContext
    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_a = NULL;
    ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a, in_filename_a, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_a %s", in_filename_a);
        return -1;
    }

    //Find Audio Stream Info
    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_a stream info");
        return -1;
    }


    printf("===========Input Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx_v, 0, in_filename_v, 0);
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx_a, 0, in_filename_a, 0);
    printf("======================================\n");


    //Output AVFormatContext
    AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot alloc OutputFromat context!");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        return -1;
    }
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

    //Alloc AVSTREAM
    int istream_index_v = 0, istream_index_a = 0, ostream_index_v = 0, ostream_index_a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx_v->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVStream* outstream;
        AVStream* in_stream = ifmt_ctx_v->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters* in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;
        if (in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            continue;

        outstream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!outstream)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return -1;
        }

        ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(outstream->codecpar, in_codecpar);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
            return -1;
        }
        outstream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
        // Remeber video stream id
        istream_index_v = i;
        ostream_index_v = 0;
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx_a->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVStream* outstream;
        AVStream* in_stream = ifmt_ctx_a->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters* in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;
        if (in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
            continue;

        outstream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!outstream)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return -1;
        }

        ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(outstream->codecpar, in_codecpar);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
            return -1;
        }
        outstream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
        // Remeber audio stream id
        istream_index_a = i;
        ostream_index_a = 1;
        break;
    }

    printf("===========Output Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
    printf("======================================\n");

    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //Write file header
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //read and write packet
    AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        AVStream* in_stream, * outstream;
        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx_v, pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        in_stream = ifmt_ctx_v->streams[pkt->stream_index];
        if (pkt->stream_index != istream_index_v)
        {
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            continue;
        }


        pkt->stream_index = ostream_index_v;
        outstream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index];
        // in log info
        log_packet(ifmt_ctx_v, pkt, "in");

        if (pkt->pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
        {
            AVRational time_base1 = in_stream->time_base;
            // 
            int64_t calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE / av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);
            static int frame_index = 0;
            pkt->pts = (double)(frame_index * calc_duration) / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
            pkt->dts = pkt->pts;
            pkt->duration = (double)calc_duration / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
            frame_index++;
        }


        // duration between two frames(us)
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, in_stream->time_base, outstream->time_base);
        pkt->pos = -1;
        // out log info
        log_packet(ofmt_ctx, pkt, "out");

        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    while (1)
    {
        AVStream* in_stream, * outstream;
        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx_a, pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        in_stream = ifmt_ctx_a->streams[pkt->stream_index];
        if (pkt->stream_index != istream_index_a)
        {
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            continue;
        }

        if (pkt->pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
        {
            AVRational time_base1 = in_stream->time_base;
            // duration between two frames(us)
            int64_t calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE / av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);
            static int frame_index = 0;
            pkt->pts = (double)(frame_index * calc_duration) / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
            pkt->dts = pkt->pts;
            pkt->duration = (double)calc_duration / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
            frame_index++;
        }

        // in log info
        log_packet(ifmt_ctx_a, pkt, "in");

        pkt->stream_index = ostream_index_a;
        outstream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index];


        //change timestamp
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, in_stream->time_base, outstream->time_base);
        pkt->pos = -1;
        // out log info
        log_packet(ofmt_ctx, pkt, "out");

        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    //write file trailer
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);


    printf("===========Output Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
    printf("======================================\n");

}
```

[DVB Insepctor video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYQXy.png)
[DVB Insepctor audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jjzv.png)

Comment: I want to mux a h264 file and a aac file to a ts file.So the fisrt loop that I read and write frames from video,the second from audio.

Comment: `av_interleaved_write_frame` uses internal buffering and will wait to receive one packet for each stream until `AVFormatContext::max_interleave_delta` after which it will dump what it buffered. This is 10s seconds by default so you probably have a large audio/video gap at the beginning of the output file. You need to send packets from all input streams to the muxer in time.

Comment: Yes,I analyse the ts file by a tool. I found that the front is all h264 packages, then add a lot of aac packages, the last small section is two kinds of packages interleaved.
For ts files, is this order not playable properly? This video is over 3 minutes total.

Comment: You can use DVB Inspector to see the timestamps visually. Yes, I think this can cause issues, I would try to properly interleave them.

Comment: I used DVB Insepctor and found that it was indeed the same as what I found before. Lots of video packages, followed by lots of audio packages, and finally both packages interleaved. It doesn't look like this way of composing packages works well. I put the pictures at the end of the article.
However, if I change the ".ts" in the code to ".mp4", the video file will play normally, why is this the case?

Comment: MP4 is indexed so it's able to locate the audio samples immediately, MPEG-TS is a stream and there's no audio packet until 10s in.

Comment: Thanks，I tried using write file according to pts time, ts video can play normally now.Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @aergistal.

- The Reason is that `av_interleaved_write_frame` has buffer limit.I
  hadn't thought about this before so I write all video packages
  firstly and then write all audio packages.In ts files, at front are
  lots of video packages, followed by lots of audio packages, and
  finally both packages interleaved.
- Because of MPEG-TS is a stream consists of packages , so in a long time the player can't find audio packages resulting no voice.

Here is my new code that can work.

```
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#define EXTRAL 1

static void log_packet(const AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx, const AVPacket* pkt, const char* tag)
{
    AVRational* time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;

    FILE* fp = fopen("fflog.log", "a+");
    char buf[200];
    sprintf(buf, "%s num=%d  den=%d\n", tag, time_base->num, time_base->den);
    for (int i = 0; *(buf + i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        fwrite(buf + i, 1, 1, fp);
    }
    sprintf(buf, "%s: pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
        tag,
        av_ts2str(pkt->pts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
        av_ts2str(pkt->dts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
        av_ts2str(pkt->duration), av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
        pkt->stream_index);
    for (int i = 0; *(buf + i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        fwrite(buf + i, 1, 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    const char* in_filename_v = "test.h264";
    const char* in_filename_a = "aoutput.aac";
    const char* out_filename = "lol.ts";


    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_v = NULL;
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_v, in_filename_v, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_v %s", in_filename_v);
        return -1;
    }

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_v, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_v stream info");
        return -1;
    }

    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_a = NULL;
    ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a, in_filename_a, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_a %s", in_filename_a);
        return -1;
    }

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_a stream info");
        return -1;
    }

#if EXTRAL
    printf("===========Input Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx_v, 0, in_filename_v, 0);
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx_a, 0, in_filename_a, 0);
    printf("======================================\n");
#endif

    AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot alloc OutputFromat context!");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        return -1;
    }
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

    int istream_index_v = 0, istream_index_a = 0, ostream_index_v = 0, ostream_index_a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx_v->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVStream* outstream;
        AVStream* in_stream = ifmt_ctx_v->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters* in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;
        if (in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            continue;

        outstream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!outstream)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return -1;
        }

        ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(outstream->codecpar, in_codecpar);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
            return -1;
        }
        outstream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
        istream_index_v = i;
        ostream_index_v = 0;
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx_a->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVStream* outstream;
        AVStream* in_stream = ifmt_ctx_a->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters* in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;
        if (in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
            continue;
        outstream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!outstream)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return -1;
        }

        ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(outstream->codecpar, in_codecpar);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
            return -1;
        }
        outstream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
        istream_index_a = i;
        ostream_index_a = 1;
        break;
    }

#if EXTRAL
    printf("===========Output Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
    printf("======================================\n");
#endif
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int64_t pts_v = 0, pts_a = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (av_compare_ts(pts_a, ifmt_ctx_a->streams[istream_index_a]->time_base, pts_v, ifmt_ctx_v->streams[istream_index_v]->time_base) <= 0)
        {

            AVStream* in_stream, * outstream;
            ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx_a, pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
                break;
            in_stream = ifmt_ctx_a->streams[pkt->stream_index];
            if (pkt->stream_index != istream_index_a)
            {
                av_packet_unref(pkt);
                continue;
            }

            if (pkt->pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
            {
                AVRational time_base1 = in_stream->time_base;
                int64_t calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE / av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);
                static int frame_index = 0;
                pkt->pts = (double)(frame_index * calc_duration) / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
                pkt->dts = pkt->pts;
                pkt->duration = (double)calc_duration / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
                frame_index++;
            }
            pts_a = pkt->pts;
            // in log info
            log_packet(ifmt_ctx_a, pkt, "in audio");

            pkt->stream_index = ostream_index_a;
            outstream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index];


            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, in_stream->time_base, outstream->time_base);
            pkt->pos = -1;
            // out log info
            log_packet(ofmt_ctx, pkt, "out audio");

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            AVStream* in_stream, * outstream;
            ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx_v, pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
                break;
            in_stream = ifmt_ctx_v->streams[pkt->stream_index];
            if (pkt->stream_index != istream_index_v)
            {
                av_packet_unref(pkt);
                continue;
            }


            pkt->stream_index = ostream_index_v;
            outstream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index];


            if (pkt->pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
            {
                AVRational time_base1 = in_stream->time_base;
                int64_t calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE / av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);
                static int frame_index = 0;
                pkt->pts = (double)(frame_index * calc_duration) / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
                pkt->dts = pkt->pts;
                pkt->duration = (double)calc_duration / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1) * AV_TIME_BASE);
                frame_index++;
            }
            pts_v = pkt->pts;

            // in log info
            log_packet(ifmt_ctx_v, pkt, "in video");

            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, in_stream->time_base, outstream->time_base);
            pkt->pos = -1;
            // out log info
            log_packet(ofmt_ctx, pkt, "out video");

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }


    ret = av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error av_write_trailer\n");
    }
#if EXTRAL
    printf("===========Output Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
    printf("======================================\n");
#endif
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx_v);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx_a);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    return 0;
}
```